# Connect ESP8266 to a network

Tags: arduino, at-command, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have connected correctly my ESP8266 to an Arduino UNO R3. It responds to AT commands but when I ask for the operation mode with AT+CWMODE? it responds with state +CWMODE:2 and as a result when I send the AT+CWLAP command the respond is an error. If I am right the CWMODE should be 3 in order to be able to connect to a Wi-Fi network. If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: probably a better fit on electronics.stackexchange.com... but if you search hackaday or similar sites, there are literally hundreds of projects using ESP8266 + arduinos; it shouldn't be hard to find an example

Comment: Thank you very much. Did a little search and came across a video. I just had to send the AT command: AT+CWMODE=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CWMODE sets the mode of connectivity.

> AT+CWMODE?  queries the actual mode.  AT+CWMODE=1 sets the mode for
>   STA.  AT+CWMODE=2 sets the mode for AP.  AT+CWMODE=3 sets the mode for
>   both AP and STA.

You can use mode 1 for actual Wifi connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, my problem is solved!